# What is a reasonable air-conditioning schedule to prevent humidity issues?

Tags: cooling, humidity

In North Florida (Jacksonville), is there an effective temperature cooling profile to ensure to avoid issues associated with excessive humidity?   Assume that I can tolerate any level of heat.   Damp-rid is deployed in closets and under sinks.

If I am out of town for a month, I would like to be able to apply a rule of thumb so that the Florida humidity does not create problems, and at the same time I would like to avoid wasting energy.

The current cooling schedule includes:

[image]

If you have experience programming thermostats to manage humidity, please state this in your response: lessons learned are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. Humidity is independent of temperature, at least above the dew point. Obviously the more your HVAC system runs, the more moisture is removed from the air. Other factors such as run time, air leakage, and human activity are more important than temperature, which must remain within a reasonable range for comfort.

Comment: I find people who have A/C are looking for any pretense to use it, and "yeah, sure I'm dehumidifying" sounds like another one of those.  A/C does do a fine job of dehumidifying, but If you actually want to dehumidify, you'd have the A/C actuated by a humidity sensor.  The problem is holding a constant temp will still permit humidity to be at 100% RH.

Answer (score 4):

This question has received a lot of answers and comments, but I suspect not from people familiar with Florida who have encountered the underlying issue.  It is a frequent one in Florida because:

- There are a lot of snowbirds, and Floridians who travel a lot, so houses frequently are unoccupied for long periods.
- Florida is extremely hot and humid.

The biggest issue is mold, which thrives in high humidity.  The problem here isn't humidity near 100%; the issue isn't the dew point or condensation.  Mold becomes a problem way before that.  The EPA recommends keeping humidity below 60% (ideally, below 50%), to prevent mold growth.

The OP is in the Jacksonville area, where the yearly average outside air humidity is at or above this threshold throughout the day (low point of 58%, day average of 76%, high point of 89%).  House insulation acts like a thermal delay, so when a house is unoccupied for an extended period, it goes through cycles when it is cooler inside and the RH spikes.  In an unoccupied house with normal air infiltration, the inside humidity will be extremely mold-friendly.

Since RH is a function of temperature and the humidity of the outside air, it is imprecise and expensive to try to handle this by arbitrarily cycling the AC based on temperature or time.  To reliably control mold, you might need to run the AC more than required.  Also, you need a reliable way of knowing what humidity level results from your normal AC temperature setting.  If it normally keeps the house close to 60% RH and you arbitrarily bump the temperature higher while you're gone, it could result in a mold-friendly environment.

The standard solution is to install a humidistat (not very expensive and a one-time cost), which cycles on the AC only as needed to keep the humidity in a range where mold doesn't grow.

Note that, as d.george writes, this is likely to be much more regular than an occasional burst of AC.  It will be removing moisture from the air, but everything in the house will be storing moisture and contributing to the equilibrium.  How much it runs based on humidity compared to how much it normally runs will depend on the humidity level resulting from your normal AC setting, and the outside temperature and humidity while you're gone.  If your normal AC setting keeps the humidity in the 50% to 60% range, the system will run about the same amount via the humidistat.  If the normal AC setting keeps the house at a low humidity, it will run a lot less via the humidistat.

Another, or auxiliary, solution is to use a dehumidifier (probably several for a whole house), as d.george suggests.  You will need a way to get rid of the collected water so it can run for an extended period unattended.  These cycle based entirely on humidity.

Answer (score 3):

Humidity is relative.  Air can hold so much water *depending on its temperature*.  If fully saturated (100%) hot air is dramatically cooled, the water must condense out, which is how clouds and rain work, and why your A/C unit has a drain.    Air at

- 95F can hold about 40 grams of water per cubic metre of air.
- 83F can hold about 25 g/cu.m.
- 60F can hold about 17 g/cu.m.
- 40F can hold about 6 g/cu.m.

100% relatve humidity is when it holds that much.

An air conditioner dries by taking hot air and dragging it across a 40F evaporator (*freon* evporating, that is). This means the air can now only hold 6 g/cu.m. And the rest of the water condenses.  By the time this air equalizes with your 83F house, it is at 25% relative humidity.  Just this air.

Unfortunately (well fortuantely for air-breathing creatures), your house leaks.  And muggy Florida 95F air is getting in, pregnant with 40g/cu.m. And this mixes back into that dry air. It's quite possible your house could be at an equilibrium of near 100% RH despite keeping the A/C at 83, depending on how serious this leakage is.

Now imagine your leakage is not so bad, and you command your A/C to slam your house down to 60F.  Suddenly the house is (worst case) 17 g/cu.m. and likely lower than that.   Then you turn the A/C off entirely. Solar load re-warms the house to 95F (probably higher), where at 17 g/cu.m. it is only 43% relative humidity (probably lower).

The trick is doing this just often enough to compensate for air change caused by leakage.

So surging the A/C several times a day is how I'd do it.  The rest of the time, let the house cook, because higher temp = lower RH for the same amount of water in the air.

Comment: Well in fairness to d.george, this is merely the underlying physics and what *I* would do, not necessarily an industry best practice.   Really you can't be black-boxing this, OP needs a proper humidity meter,  preferably with nice logging like he has for the temp.  That log data will tell you everything.

Comment: @Harper, this is a great idea but the more I think about it, the more I suspect it wouldn't work in Florida.  Typical AC units have a hard time maintaining indoor temperature and humidity at such a big difference from what's outside.  If you let the indoor temp go up like that, you couldn't kick on the AC for a short time and knock it down to 60 (in the summer, you'd probably have a hard time reaching 60 if you ran it continuously).  I think you're right in your comment that any solution needs to start with the actual humidity as a basis.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to control humidity in a home is by running some type of equipment that will reduce that humidity, and those are an A/C unit and a dehumidifier. Short blasts of A/C will not reduce or let you control the amount of humidity in your home. Remember that the whole house and it's contents are at the same temp. and humidity. that means the air, bed and bedding, all the furniture and furnishings, floors, the floor coverings, everything inside that home and to some extent even the insulation in the walls and they do not easily and instantly give up their moisture or heat. It takes time to reduce the temperature and especially the humidity, in the house.

Oversized air-conditioners will not reduce the humidity a great amount since they do not run long enough to remove enough water. (Surging the A/C several times a day is not the answer or the solution.) and (A/C does not do a fine job of dehumidifing unless it is able to run a very long time). Under sized A/C units  do the best job of reducing the humidity.

If you are leaving town for an extended period of time, set  the A/C about 5 degrees warmer than when you are there to reduce your cooling costs. DO NOT TURN THE A/C OFF. If you can't reduce the humidity with just the A/C unit then that A/C unit is probably too big for the house and you should add a dehumidifier to reduce the humidity.

My house located about 30 miles north of Pittsburgh, Pa., has 4000 sq feet of conditioned space and is cooled by a 3 ton A/C unit. I need to run a dehumidifier to keep the humidity below 40%.

Comment: You've got some excellent points here.  The only things preventing my upvote are that it starts with a rant, and I would question an arbitrary 5 degrees warmer setting.  The current setting could have the RH just below the mold threshold.

Comment: Indoor mold is a huge problem in Florida because of the high humidity and temperature.  Indoor air can feel clammy even when the AC is running.  It's even worse if people oversize their AC trying to achieve more temperature drop (as you describe).  At the regular temperature setting, the humidity can already be almost to the level where mold blooms (> 60% or so RH).  My point about the arbitrary 5 degrees is that that reduction in AC can lead to a mold bloom.  The 5 degree strategy is pretty safe in the northern states but in Florida it can mean returning to a pungent house and a cleanup job.

Comment: @d.george Please pay mind to [rule #1](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @d.george  How did you arrive at a target of 40% RH?  Is this a good rule of thumb?

Comment: When the humidity in my house is between 30% and  40%,it feels comfortable- not sticky and not dry. If it goes above 45% every one in the house complains.

Comment: When the humidity in my house is between 3

Comment: My deleted statement on May 18th, that a moderator deleted was an exact answer as to how humidity works. It may not have been deemed as an answer to the particular question asked but it was 100% accurate. I don't understand why good answers and comments are deleted while other stuff that is written that makes no sense is praised as gospel. I guess that the moderators are not looking for expert answers just jibberish. Sometimes I wonder why I even try.

Answer (score -1):

> What is a reasonable air-conditioning schedule to prevent humidity issues?

## Off.

Humidity is not a problem as long as the outside, hot and humid air does not encounter something cooler, like inside of an AC'd home or car. If you're leaving the town, just turn the AC off. The inside of your house will warm up to the outside temperatures, so there will be no problems with humidity condensing.

If you want to have relative humidity lower than 100%, you have to heat the home up a bit. Sun will do that for free once you turn the AC off.